# why doesnt my root sass file import from my navbar sass file with the import function?

Tags: css, sass

I'm on VScode using SASS and I have a separate file for my navbar but when I try importing the file to my main SASS file which auto compiles (using live server and live sass compiler), it won't update any changes to my navbar on my practice website.

I'm using @import 'navbar'; in my root sass file, am I missing any extensions or downloads?

Comment: How about showing your imports? No one can answer without seeing what you are trying to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.